# Batch update returned unexpected row count from update; actual row count: 0; expected: 1 when delete operation using NHibernate

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, queryover

I use NHibernate in c# and perform delete operation:
My problem is that, When I login by 'A' user on 'PC1' and also login by same user on 'PC2' because I provide no. of session 2 for this user and delete one

record from 'PC1' record deleted successfully, But when same record delete from 'PC2' without refreshing page.then it gives exception as follows:

**"Batch update returned unexpected row count from update; actual row count: 0; expected: 1"**

here my code is :

```
public void Delete(object instance)
        {
            using(NHSession.BeginTransaction())
            {
                NHSession.Delete(instance);
                NHSession.Transaction.Commit();
            }
        }
```

here -

NHSession.Transaction.Commit(); this line gives error when I delete from 'PC2'.
so here how to handle this problem using NHibernate.
After executing this make **sql query as follows:**

```
DELETE FROM [Employee].[dbo].Employee_Master WHERE EmpID = @p0;@p0 = d3b9df34-97c6-450a-a570-a62000dd5125 [Type: Guid (0)]
```

and when same query execute in sql Studio then it return following **o/p**:

***(0 row(s) affected)***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's caused by a weird way of coping with transactions or detached entities. When you avoid deleting detached entities directly, it doesn't happen.

I don't know why your transaction looks like this.

Either you should have started the transaction from some higher layer (never manage transactions from within the data access layer), 
or you get the object from the client directly and should load it as attached instance. In that case, you should only get the id from the client instead of the detached instance:

```
public void DeleteUserSession(Guid id)
{
    using(NHSession.BeginTransaction())
    {
      var instance = NHSession.Get(typeof(UserSession), id);
      if (instance != null)
      {
        NHSession.Delete(instance);
      }
      NHSession.Transaction.Commit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Stefan,
I agree with your answer and this solution I was already known but here I don't want to get record from Id or I don't want to check record already exist or not, I want return value 0. because I put my sql query in my question and sql give 0 return value. but NH give exception. so I want solution without getting record.

Comment: You need to load the entity from the database in order to delete it with NH. (OK, there is a delete-HQL statement, you can also use plain SQL, but these options have their draw backs.). Trying to delete an entity which is in memory (as in your case) but not in the database (as in your case) is treated as a concurrency problem (which it actually is). It needs rolling back the transaction - therefore the exception.

Comment: Yes, Stefan HQL query is one another option and I use this option already but I want to do this only through NH. Because I know sql query give me (0 row(s) affected) but why NH not do this. I find on many sites but not give any one particular answer or reason.so how to do this?.

Comment: I tried to explain the reason before: Trying to delete an entity which is in memory but not in the database is treated as a concurrency problem (which it actually is). It means that the transaction conflicts with another concurrent transaction. The memory state cannot be synchronized with the database. It needs rolling back the transaction - which is forced with an exception.

Comment: I use HQL query to temporary workaround for this issue.and it is working fine. but I want to handle this issue NHibernate.